# HTML: Changing the URL without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate

Check out this link:

http://google.blogspot.com/view/timeslide

And click on the post and as you can see the URL is changing but without a # or something like that, It changes like the page would load normally, but the content changes just like it would be built with AJAX.

This happens with Chrome 10 with the latest stable version, but for Firefox 3.6 it uses the  old way with the hash :)

How is this possible, is this a new HTML5 feature or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify the URL without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-to-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[pushState](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-history-pushstate):

> `window . history . pushState(data, title [, url ] )`
>
> Pushes the given data onto the session history, with the given title, and, if provided, the given URL...
>
> the user agent must run the following steps...
>
> Add a state object entry to the session history, after the [current entry](http://web.archive.org/web/20100328092909/http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#current-entry), with *cloned data* as the state object, the given *title* as the title, and, if the third argument is present, the [absolute URL](http://web.archive.org/web/20100328092909/http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/urls.html#absolute-url) that was found earlier in this algorithm as the [URL](http://web.archive.org/web/20100328092909/http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/urls.html#url) of the entry.
>
> Update the [current entry](http://web.archive.org/web/20100328092909/http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#current-entry) to be the this newly added entry...